# HTML to Javascript to PHP parameters giving weird values

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm currently using Codeigniter to do basic CRUD. I have the following code

JS

```
function approve(args){
if(confirm('Do you want to approve this document?')){
                    window.location = "http://52.45.5.57/index.php/FinalizeCase/approve/" + args;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
```

HTML with some PHP to loop all the PKs to generate something like this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve" onclick="approve(0000000004)"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve" onclick="approve(0000000008)"/>
```

But the weird this is, sometimes when I click the links I get really weird values i.e. for 15 I got 13. I thought maybe I mixed the loops or something and tried changing a cell to 215~ and when I tested it I got 140 even though my max cell and DB is around 15 excluding the one I raised for testing.

Checked the link params before clicking and it checked out with the corresponding value in the cell.

Tried using the following but it stayed the same, 251 becomes 141 and 12 becomes 8.

1. use a button instead of an input tag
2. use unique names and values in the html tag

Comment: Your submits need to be unique.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Both have the same names and value.

Comment: Did something similar to name$i and value$i but it stayed the same

Comment: Also tried using a button but to no avail.

Comment: If this is a php question, you'll have to edit your post to contain what it was. Also, in php `0000000004` without being quoted is taken as an octal with the leading zero(s).

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the leading zeroes?
You're experiencing one of the disadvantages of loosely-typed languages such as php or JavaScript: the interpretor decides what type is each variable, not you. It saves work most of the time because "it just works" but sometimes the data type chosen by the interpreter is not what you'd expect and you end up here.

You may think your args are either strings or integers with a lot of leading zeroes, but the interpreters are actually seeing Octal numbers (which, when converted to decimal, change)

Depending on what is the actual type you expect, you have many alternatives:

If you expect the argument to be treated as a string, you need to keep the leading zeroes but prevent any interpretation as octal like this

```
function approve(args)
{
var a = String(args); // force the type to string
if(confirm('Do you want to approve this document?'))
{
   window.location = "http://52.45.5.57/index.php/FinalizeCase/approve/" + a;

 }

else 
{
  return false;
}
```

Just to be safe, you may also want to take the value in your controller and cast it as a string too. Assuming the args is also called $args in your PHP part, you may do something like

```
public function approve( (string) $args = null)
{
    // Do whatever you need to do
}
```

This would also be my recommended course of action if your args are a zero-padded integer in the database.

If you need to considers args are strings, you should trim the leading zeroes and cast as int using `parseInt();` in JavaScript and/or `$args = (int) $args;` in php

Answer (score -1):

Like @Funk Forty Niner said.

The solution is simple, just remove the leading zeroes.

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');
```